# How to Automate Redshift Cluster Start/Stop for night time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a AWS Redshift Cluster dc2.8xlarge and currently I am paying huge bill each month for running the cluster 24/7.

Is there a way I can automate the cluster uptime so that the cluster will be running in day time and I can stop the cluster at 8PM in evening and again start it in 8AM in morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

good news :)

Now we can able to pause and resume the Redshift cluster (both Console and CLI)

check out the link:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/lower-your-costs-with-the-new-pause-and-resume-actions-on-amazon-redshift/

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** Stop/Start is now available. See: [Amazon Redshift launches pause and resume](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/03/amazon-redshift-launches-pause-resume/)

---

Amazon Redshift **does not have a Start/Stop concept**. However, there are a few options...

You could **resize the cluster** so that it is a lower-cost. A Redshift Cluster is sized for Compute and for Storage. You could reduce the number of nodes as long as you retain enough nodes for your Storage needs.

Also, Amazon Redshift has introduced [RA3 nodes with managed storage enabling independent compute and storage scaling](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/12/amazon-redshift-announces-ra3-nodes-managed-storage/), which means you might be able scale-down to a single node. (This is a new node type, I'm not sure of how it works.)

Another option is to **take a Snapshot and Shutdown the cluster**. This will result in no costs for the cluster (but the Snapshot will be charged). Then, **create a new cluster from the Snapshot** when you want the cluster again.

**Scheduling** the above can be done in Amazon CloudWatch Events, which can trigger an AWS Lambda function. Within the function, you can make the necessary API calls to the Amazon Redshift service.

If you are concerned with the general cost of your cluster, you might want to downside from the `dc2.8xlarge`. You could either use multiple `dc2.large` nodes, or even consider a move to `ds2.xlarge`, which is a lower cost per TB of data stored.

Answer (score 0):

Now we can pause and resume an AWS Redshift cluster.

We can also schedule the pause and the resume, which is a very important feature to check on the costs.


Link: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/lower-your-costs-with-the-new-pause-and-resume-actions-on-amazon-redshift/


This will help you in automating the cluster uptime & downtime so that the cluster will be running in day time and is paused automatically at a specific time in the evening and again start in the morning automatically.

Answer (score 0):

its pretty easy to use opensource https://cloudcustodian.io to automate nightime/weekend off hours on redshift and other aws resources.